# Dictionary order when keys are numbers

Tags: python, dictionary

We know that regular Python dictionaries are unordered, but what about the case when the keys are the set of natural numbers? The `hash` function seems to be an identity function when the domain is the set of natural numbers, and iterating over something like `x = {0:'a', 1:'b', 2:'c'}` seems to yield the natural order of the keys, aka 0, 1, 2..

So can this behavior be relied on?

(Yes I know about OrderedDict)

EDIT:

Here's my specific usage, or at least this captures the spirit of what I'm looking at.

`x = dict((a, chr(a)) for a in range(10))`

`for i in x:
    print i`

This seems to preserve order.

Comment: Chances are you just got lucky, I wouldn't rely on it.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on somethings that's not documented :(

Comment: @PauloBu Well I mean the C source code is I guess the documentation, I just don't have the time to look at it. But from what I understand, the interpreter takes the hash of a key for the array placement for the dict.

Comment: If you just need it to be sorted, you can use `sorted(x)`. You can't rely on any particular order in general.

Comment: Guys, I'm not getting reasons beyond 'just because'. Dictionaries take a hash of a key for the placement, so my question is if there is ever a case when the hash of a natural number wouldn't be the same natural number.

Comment: Ok you made your point about the _real doc_. Confirm your suspicions about the identity being the hash of the integers: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3a1db0d2747e/Objects/intobject.c#l461. It is true except for -1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope. Never, ever, ever rely on the order of the dictionary keys. An illustrative example:

```
>>> {0: 1, 8: 2}
{0: 1, 8: 2}
>>> {8: 1, 0: 2}
{8: 1, 0: 2}
```

This happens because a dictionary starts off with 8 buckets. Thus, 0 and 8 end up in the same bucket, which will cause an immediate collision. The order depends on which is inserted first. (But don't rely on that either: that initial size isn't a guarantee!)

You are correct, however, that the `hash` of `int`s (in Python 2.x) is the identity function (with the sole exception of `-1`, which is mapped to `-2` to avoid collision with the usual "error return" value). However, the distinction between `int` and `long` is quite subtle sometimes, and `long`s use a different hashing algorithm (because they can be arbitrarily large).

Comment: Hell of a good example! By the way, with `ipython`, {8:0,0:1} don't work as the example.

Comment: It appears that `dict` doesn't actually use `hash` directly. For example on a 32-bit system: `hash(1<<33) = 2` while `{1<<33:"foo"} = {8589934592L: 'foo'}`

Comment: Nice minimal example. I recalled needing more keys to see this

Comment: @PauloBu: I think `ipython` sorts the keys for display (it shows a different result then `repr` does).

Comment: @Cuadue: `dict` stores the actual objects, and only uses `hash` to look them up quickly. The hash value used isn't visible to you, but it is definitely using the equivalent of the `hash` function.

Comment: @Cuadue, `dict` _must_ use it's own internal hash (dependant on the size of the dict). Otherwise you'd need a 4GB(or more) hash table for each and every dict!

Comment: @nneonneo of course! `hash("foo") != {"foo":"bar"}.keys()[0]`

Comment: @Cuadue: Of course what? `"foo"` is never going to be equal to its hash (a 32- or 64-bit integer).

Comment: @nneonneo Thank you, perhaps I should show my example:
`x = dict((a, chr(a) for a in range(10)`, iterating over that gives me the keys in order.

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian: If you insert numerical keys in order, you will probably get them out in the same order. This is because the keys don't move when the hash table expands, so the keys won't become unordered. But that's just because you inserted them in sequence; if you inserted them in reverse order, for example, you'll get something different.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot rely on that behaviour.   It is an implementation detail which can change from one version of Python to the next or even from one system to the next.

That being said, it is unlikely to change soon.

Comment: What if I'm stuck on one Python version.

Comment: As long as you are stuck also on one system, you should be safe.  To be super safe, you could look at the implementation (the C sources of the Python interpreter).

Answer (score 0):

No. The order also depends on the order the keys are inserted.